# Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to add data to my Google Cloud SQL database using Google App Script. My code was working fine last night when I finished but when I ran it this morning it is now giving me the error "statement cancelled due to timeout or client request", the error I am getting in the cloud console is "Got an error reading communication packets".

Last night it was processing about 1,600 lines of data. I have played around with it and narrowed it down that the error will occur when there is more the 15 lines. 15 lines it will add the data fine, change it to 16 lines and it throws the error, this tells me that it is not the connection itself. I have also tested the data in the spreadsheet by copying line 15 into line 16 and deleting all other data, this did not work. My main confusion with everything I have read saying it is timing out, is that it was working fine last night with 1,600 rows of data. My code is below:

```
function connection(folderId, db, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var excelfile = files.next();
  var fileId = excelfile.getId();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId).getSheetByName('Report 1');
  var last = data.getLastRow()
  var sheetdata=data.getRange("B5:H16").getValues();

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);//dburl is not defined

  conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO '+ db + ' ' + '('+c1+','+c2+','+c3+','+c4+','+c5+','+c6+','+c7+') values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i=0; i<sheetdata.length; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1, Utilities.formatDate(sheetdata[i][0], 'Etc/GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    stmt.setString(2, sheetdata[i][1]);
    stmt.setString(3, sheetdata[i][2]);
    stmt.setString(4, sheetdata[i][3]);
    stmt.setString(5, sheetdata[i][4]);
    stmt.setString(6, sheetdata[i][5]);
    stmt.setString(7, sheetdata[i][6]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
      var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
      conn.commit();
      conn.close();

var end = new Date()
Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting if you log the values from `sheetdata`? You mentioned that the code fails at the 16th line, what does this line contain? @MarkWarren

Comment: Its not the data, I get an 2d array when I log the data. I have copied the line 15 data and added it to the line 16 to see if it was the actual data that was causing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that the issue is with the new App Script Runtime V8. For a fix, change your runtime back to Rhino. To do this go to "View > Show project manifest" then where it says "runtimeVersion": "V8" change this to be "runtimeVersion": "STABLE". There is currently an open bug on this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function connection(folderId, db, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("fileId");//just go to the file and get the id
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Report 1');
  var rg=sh.getRange("B5:H16");
  var sheetdata=rg.getValues();
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);//dburl is not defined
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO '+ db + ' ' + '('+c1+','+c2+','+c3+','+c4+','+c5+','+c6+','+c7+') values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i=0; i<sheetdata.length; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1, Utilities.formatDate(sheetdata[i][0], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    stmt.setString(2, sheetdata[i][1]);
    stmt.setString(3, sheetdata[i][2]);
    stmt.setString(4, sheetdata[i][3]);
    stmt.setString(5, sheetdata[i][4]);
    stmt.setString(6, sheetdata[i][5]);
    stmt.setString(7, sheetdata[i][6]);
    stmt.addBatch();   
  }
  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: That did not work, question I have is why have you got a j for statement but not using j? Also sheetdata.length is one, I have an array that looks like this [[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]]

Comment: I don't think so sheetdata looks like [[],[],[],....2d

Comment: Check the documentation for [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) what does it return?

Comment: I am 100% sure it is [[[],[],[]]] as I have logged sheetdata as I was building this out. Also as I mentioned in my question if I do getRange("B5:H15") it works fine and I get the data I was expecting.

Comment: Yes...Sorry the j was not needed.  But sheetdata[0] was the width not the length

Comment: If you want to argue with the documentation that's your decision but it's wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Okay I see what you were doing you pushed your array into sheetdata I change that just now.

Comment: This is the log from app script https://imgur.com/a/d5ETkNm.

Comment: Sorry I changed in your question but I meant to change it in my answer and I corrected both now.  But the better choice is to just go with the 2D array.

Comment: I can't see any changes to your answer sorry. I understand it might be better but I don't see how it would change anything? Also thanks for trying to help

Comment: I changed it to a 2d array and it is still not working :(

Comment: And can you update the code in your question so that I can see what you have

Comment: I rewrote it and simplifed a bit and I notice dburl is not defined

Comment: I updated my code to reflect on what change I have made. It is still not working. When I say not working I am still getting the ""statement cancelled due to timeout or client request""

Comment: What line is it failing on?  If you not looking at view/executions then look there please.

Comment: Yes dburl is undefined because it is held somewhere else in the code and I have not included it due to sensitive nature. It is nothing to do with connecting to the database as it connect fine when I change the range to 15 lines ands my data to the data base. It is failing on line "var batch = stmt.executeBatch();"

Comment: Why are you  using executeBatch when you're only giving it one command?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc